# Режется HTML форматирование в multipart письме

Tags: html, email, smtp, gmail, рассылка

Пытаюсь сделать по аналогу другого письма `multipart` письмо. Но GMail режет все HTML теги и отображает письмо из второй части, но без форматирования. Как исправить это? Исходник письма:

```
Delivered-To: xxx@gmail.com
Received: by 10.79.105.193 with SMTP id e184csp1732294ivc;
        Tue, 31 May 2016 01:57:19 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.25.210.205 with SMTP id j196mr3546366lfg.139.1464685039688;
        Tue, 31 May 2016 01:57:19 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <webmaster@xxxx.com>
Received: from s05****.fastvps-server.com (s05***.fastvps-server.com. [2a03:f480:1:xxxxx])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id qm4si72520lbb.68.2016.05.31.01.57.19
        for <xxx@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Tue, 31 May 2016 01:57:19 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of webmaster@xxxx.com designates 2a03:f480:1:xxxxx as permitted sender) client-ip=2a03:f480:1:xxxxx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@xxxx.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of webmaster@xxxx.com designates 2a03:f480:1:xxxxx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=webmaster@xxxx.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=xxxx.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=xxxx.com; s=dkim;
    h=Date:Message-Id:List-Id:List-Unsubscribe:Content-Type:Reply-To:From:Subject:To; bh=DjWJSTXiHxh3erjnZcsVVDLhoKAx3FvkKujJ4BLQZXY=;
    b=06BOCMwbNIfb5Di3XDL8f7JIBn7n9bR+HAZsWRpGgihUmSag79//qOje+juwQpwDUmMOlMrcXGqQE3At1VZz15QRTQ+yKOvekH4LLoAkljqGw3yJTQtuK7T1UMPMHUadKEswGkum+1Gmw6TAuTZvenmJ3i05pXFFIE5dZGuIHWE=;
Received: from www-data by s05657567.fastvps-server.com with local (Exim 4.84_2)
    (envelope-from <webmaster@xxxx.com>)
    id 1b7fUF-0005jm-B4
    for xxx@gmail.com; Tue, 31 May 2016 11:57:19 +0300
To: xxx@gmail.com
Subject: Confirm Your Registration
From: XX XX <money@xxxx.com>
Reply-To: support@xxxx.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=ahQEtHYFz8RDrhtBhzK7raifn75e2T
List-Unsubscribe: <https://xxxx.com/unfollow?user_id=1&code=4iadh25Br5nYY543Q>
List-Id: <register-confirmation>
Message-Id: <E1b7fUF-0005jm-B4@s05657567.fastvps-server.com>
Date: Tue, 31 May 2016 11:57:19 +0300

--ahQEtHYFz8RDrhtBhzK7raifn75e2T
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Mime-Version: 1.0

Please See English version below 
---------------------------------
Пожалуйста, перейдите по https://xxxx.com/activateAccount?user_id=1&code=4iadh25Br5nYY543Q , чтобы подтвердить регистрацию. Вы подписываетесь на нашу рассылку, урегулировать которую вы можете в личном кабинете.
----------------------------------
Please, follow https://xxxx.com/activateAccount?user_id=1&code=4iadh25Br5nYY543Q , to confirm your account. That's also confirm subscription to our services.
<br/>
Unfollow / Отписаться: https://xxxx.com/unfollow?user_id=1&code=4iadh25Br5nYY543Q


--ahQEtHYFz8RDrhtBhzK7raifn75e2T
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Mime-Version: 1.0

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Confirm Your Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
https://xxxx.com/activateAccount?user_id=1&code=4iadh25Br5nYY543Q
Please See English version below <br/>
<hr/><br/>
Пожалуйста, перейдите по <a href='https://xxxx.com/activateAccount?user_id=1&code=4iadh25Br5nYY543Q'>следующей ссылке</a>, чтобы подтвердить регистрацию. Вы подписываетесь на нашу рассылку, урегулировать которую вы можете в личном кабинете.<br/>
<hr/><br/>
Please, follow <a href='https://xxxx.com/activateAccount?user_id=1&code=4iadh25Br5nYY543Q'>this link</a>, to confirm your account. That's also confirm subscription to our services.<br/>
<br/>
<a href="https://xxxx.com/unfollow?user_id=1&code=4iadh25Br5nYY543Q"><b>Unfollow / Отписаться</b></a>
</body>
</html>

--ahQEtHYFz8RDrhtBhzK7raifn75e2T--
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
> ```

Не вижу ничего похожего на `quoted-printable`. Возможно, этот заголовок надо удалить. Либо наоборот привести содержимое к надлежащему виду.